# "Unit sample response" relation to “step reponse” $(u[n] \to \delta[n])$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convolution

Book says:

$$\delta[n]=u[n] - u[n-1]$$

Therefore, the **unit sample reponse** $h[n]$ is related to **unit step reponse**, $s[n]$, as follows:

$$h[n]=s[n] - s[n-1]$$

My question is, how to prove this relationship?

**Here are a few related definitions:**

$$n\in\mathbb{Z}$$

*Step Function:*

$$u[n] = \begin{cases}1&,\text{if }n\ge0\\0&,\text{else}\end{cases}$$

*Impulse Function:*

$$\delta[n] =  \begin{cases}1&,\text{if }n=0\\0&,\text{else}\end{cases}$$

*Unit Sample Response*
$$s[n] = h[n] * u[n] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} h[n-k]u[k]$$
':

Comment: It is not quite clear what mean with e.g. `u[n] = (n>= 0) ? 1 : 0` and `\delta[n] = (n== 0) ? 1 : 0 `.What does the term `1:0` stands for? Please make clear what you want to state with these terms. Consider to plug in some free space by using `~` within the MathJax 
environment.

Comment: sorry, i'm trying to fix that...  my latex converter has a problem.

Comment: Try to explain what exactly you want to write. I can do the MathJax for you.

Comment: @mrtaurho That looks like the ternary? operator in `C`, where the expression `A?B:C` in mathspeak could be written $$\begin{cases} B & A\text{ is true} \\ C & A\text{ is false} \end{cases} $$

Comment: its a ternary.   I was just using the ternary "operator" from c-programming language because i couldn't figure out how to put the brackets in.

Comment: Give me a moment.

Comment: @BillMoore if you mean the thing I typed, you can right click on it and choose "Show Math As" to see how it was typed

Answer (score 1):

wait, I forget that convolution operator is distributive.

$$ s[n] - s[n-1] = h[n] * u[n] - h[n] * u[n-1]$$
$$ s[n] - s[n-1] = h[n] * (u[n] - u[n-1])$$
$$ s[n] - s[n-1] = h[n] * \delta[n]$$
$$ s[n] - s[n-1] = h[n] $$